# wordpress meta box\custom fields validation

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, validation, meta-boxes

I am trying to validate custom meta box fields. On the server side I tried to use "return false" on the "save_post" action, but WP disregards it (apparently the save_post is called after the post is already inserted to the DB).
I then resorted to JQuery on the client-side, but using "return false" froze the page, and it stopped responding, as if I was using an infinite loop.

the code is plain and simple:

```
         $("#post").submit(function(){
         if ($("input[name='post_title']").val()==='') {return false;};
         });
```

Any ideas? Maybe built-in WP functionality?

Comment: Could you post the jQuery code? :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The WordPress SE site has some good stuff on this topic..

Server side validation is obviously preferable.. can't rely on javascript.

[This topic](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/715/objective-best-practices-for-plugin-development/16246#16246) has a good discussion on how WP lets you handle errors.

I haven't tried implementing anything like this on meta boxes, so I can't say for sure it'll solve your problem, but hopefully it will put you on the right track.

Comment: What is the WordPress SE website?